# How can I show rating in product comments

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

My models:

```
class Comment(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product ,on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='comments')
    user = models.ForeignKey(User ,on_delete=models.CASCADE, max_length=80, related_name='comments_user')
    body = models.TextField()
    created_on = jmodels.jDateField(auto_now_add=True)
    created_on_time = models.TimeField(auto_now_add=True,null=True)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['created_on'] 

    def __str__(self):
        return 'Comment {} by {}'.format(self.body, self.user)

class Rating(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product ,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User ,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    score = models.IntegerField(default=0,
        validators=[
            MaxValueValidator(5),
            MinValueValidator(0),
        ]
    )

    def __str__(self):
        return 'rate {} by {} for {}'.format(self.score, self.user, self.product)
```

In product single page, I have comments part that I want show user rating if that user put comment  in next of username and comment date.

My views :

```
def product_details(request, category_url, subcategory_url, product_url):
    product = get_object_or_404(Product, product_url=product_url)
    stocks = Stock.objects.filter(product=product)
    rate = Rating.objects.filter(product=product, user=request.user)
    all_rates = Rating.objects.filter(product=product)
    all_rate_count = Rating.objects.filter(product=product).count()
    all_rate = sum([all_rate.score for all_rate in all_rates])
    all_rate = all_rate/all_rate_count
    all_rate = all_rate*100/5
    comments = product.comments.filter(product=product, active=True)
    if request.method == "POST":
        body = request.POST['body']
        new_comment = Comment(user=request.user,product=product, body=body)
        new_comment.save()
        message_good = "نظر شما با موفقیت ثبت شد بعد از برسی نمایش داده میشود!"
        ctx = {'product':product, 'stocks':stocks, 'rate':rate, 'all_rate':all_rate,
            'comments':comments,
            'message_good':message_good,
            'all_rate_count':all_rate_count}
        return render(request, 'products/product_details.html', ctx)
    ctx = {'product':product, 'stocks':stocks, 'rate':rate, 'all_rate':all_rate,
     'comments':comments,
     'all_rate_count':all_rate_count}
    return render(request, 'products/product_details.html', ctx)
```

And my html :

```
{% for comment in comments %}
<div class="comments" style="padding: 10px;">
  <p class="font-weight-bold">
    {{ comment.user }}
    <span class=" text-muted font-weight-normal">
      {{ comment.created_on }}
    </span>
    <span class=" text-muted font-weight-normal">
      {{ comment.created_on_time|date:"G:i" }}
    </span>
  </p>
  {{ comment.body | linebreaks }}
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

I updated my codes, and showed my views and my single html
so if please can help me about showing product rate by user for each comment that filtered by user.
or any better suggestion for other ways about rating or showing comments for single product page. thanks for helping

Comment: Can you add what you have so far?

Comment: @DeanElliott I don't understand sorry, can you explain more please ?

Comment: Can you show the code you have so far on the product single page? So we can help you fix it or modify it.

Comment: @DeanElliott I updated my question, please check it

Answer (score 0):

I would add a `unique_together` constraint to enforce that a user can only leave a single rating for a product.

```
class Rating(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product ,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User ,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    score = models.IntegerField(default=0,
        validators=[
            MaxValueValidator(5),
            MinValueValidator(0),
        ]
    )

  class Meta:
    unique_together = ('product', 'user')

    def __str__(self):
        return 'rate {} by {} for {}'.format(self.score, self.user, self.product)
```

In your views, since you will only have one rating for a product per user.

```
rate = Rating.objects.get(product=product, user=request.user)
```

In your templates:

```
{% for comment in comments %}
<div class="comments" style="padding: 10px;">
  <p class="font-weight-bold">
    {{ comment.user }}
    <span class=" text-muted font-weight-normal">
      {{ comment.created_on }}
    </span>
    <span class=" text-muted font-weight-normal">
      {{ comment.created_on_time|date:"G:i" }}
    </span>
  </p>
  {{ comment.body | linebreaks }}

  {{ rate.score }}
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thanks for helping, but I want each user can just have rate a product just one time and after that just can edit it. its kind of like that if one user put more than one comment, just show that one rate he did at first, the score be same at all comments for that specific user

Comment: And please if tell me how can I do that just a user can put one rating for one product not more

Comment: I've updated the answer with `unique_together` to enforce a single rating.

Comment: Thank you ! I would be glad if you help me for another issue